# Calling OpenSSL's PEM_write_PUBKEY || PEM_write_PrivateKey API makes the program to exit abruptly with message "no OPENSSL_Applink"

Tags: c, openssl, cryptography, rsa, public-key-encryption

I am trying to use EVP_* APIs from OpenSSL, but I have encountered a weird strange behavior when trying to dump the Public/Private key from the EVP_PKEY struct.

**Issue**:: After populating the EVP_PKEY struct, on calling `PEM_write_PUBKEY` API (see TRIAL1), the program exits. The same happens on calling of `PEM_write_PrivateKey` API (see TRIAL2).

**Output**: I am left with a `temp.pem` 0 bytes file and a message on cmd prompt saying `OPENSSL_Uplink(5D8C7000,08): no OPENSSL_Applink`

```
#define TRIAL1

void InitOpenSSLLib(void)
{
    SSL_library_init();
    SSL_load_error_strings();
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    EVP_PKEY_CTX* ctx = NULL;
    EVP_PKEY* pKeyPair = EVP_PKEY_new();

    BIO *mem = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    FILE* fp = fopen("temp.pem", "wb");

    InitOpenSSLLib();

    ctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_id(EVP_PKEY_RSA, 0);
    EVP_PKEY_keygen_init(ctx);
    EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_keygen_bits(ctx, 2048);
    EVP_PKEY_keygen(ctx, &pKeyPair);

    // Succeeds till here... all of the above called APIs return value greater than 0

#ifdef TRIAL1
    // Program exits even before printing any error
    if (PEM_write_PUBKEY(fp, pKeyPair) <= 0)
        printf("PEM_write_PUBKEY failed\n");
#elif TRIAL2
    // same behavior with this API too
    PEM_write_PrivateKey(fp, pKeyPair, NULL, NULL, 0, 0, NULL);
#endif
    // Tried this too.... but the control never reaches here
    fflush(fp);

    // Tried this too... most of the mem struct members are NULL.
    EVP_PKEY_print_private(mem, pKeyPair, 0, 0);

    //.... Cleanup codes
    fclose(fp);
    BIO_free_all(mem);

    return 0;
}
```

Any pointers? Am I doing anything wrong here? Is there any other way to dump private/public key or the pair PEM format to a file?

I am using VC++ 2015. Also, on hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, the prompt shows the message:: **OPENSSL_Uplink(5D8C7000,08): no OPENSSL_Applink**

<sub>Answering my own question for future devs</sub>

Comment: So, what exactly is the result? A file "temp.pem" with 0 bytes?

Comment: @Ctx: Exactly..

Comment: Does that help? https://www.openssl.org/docs/faq.html#PROG2

Comment: I have gone through that. I am compiling with /MD flag. I coudn't understand what they have written in the second paragraph reagrding `applink.c`.

Comment: Did you try to `#include <openssl/applink.c>` at the top of your code?

Comment: Couldn't find `applink.c` file in my root OpenSSL folder or lib or include folder.

Comment: What does `EVP_PKEY_keygen_init`,  `EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_keygen_bits`, and `EVP_PKEY_keygen` return? You seem to be ignoring the return codes.

Comment: @jww - Just to avoid the mess, I removed all error handling/reporting codes here. All the APIs are returning success i.e., int value greater than 0. I have found the solution. Thanks for your time though. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key question here is the error (read, message) thrown by OpenSSL, i.e., **no OPENSSL_Applink**.

As documented [here](https://www.openssl.org/docs/faq.html#PROG2),

> As per 0.9.8 the above limitation is eliminated for .DLLs. OpenSSL
>   .DLLs compiled with some specific run-time option [**we insist on the
>   default /MD**] can be deployed with application compiled with different
>   option or even different compiler. **But there is a catch! Instead of
>   re-compiling OpenSSL toolkit, as you would have to with prior
>   versions, you have to compile small C snippet with compiler and/or
>   options of your choice. The snippet gets installed as
>   /include/openssl/applink.c and should be either added to
>   your application project or simply #include-d in one [and only one] of
>   your application source files. Failure to link this shim module into
>   your application manifests itself as fatal "no OPENSSL_Applink"
>   run-time error.** An explicit reminder is due that in this situation
>   [mixing compiler options] it is as important to add CRYPTO_malloc_init
>   prior first call to OpenSSL.

you should check your compiling options for `/MD` (assuming you know the `Code Generation` options under `VC++ Project Properties`).

I did the same, but still my issue didn't get resolved. The answer to this is the second paragraph to the link given [https://www.openssl.org/docs/faq.html#PROG2], where it instructs us to include `<install-root>/include/openssl/applink.c`

> Where to get this `applink.c` file if not found in openssl's
>    dir?

In my case, I installed OpenSSL using exe binary and I couldn't find this specific `applink.c` file anywhere in my `<install-root>`, so I started looking and found it [here on GitHub](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/ms/applink.c).

**All you have to do is, include this file as source file in your project or better save it in openssl install-root dir, so that you can include it from the same location for other projects too.**

```
// applink.c from https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/ms/applink.c
/*
 * Copyright 2004-2016 The OpenSSL Project Authors. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Licensed under the OpenSSL license (the "License").  You may not use
 * this file except in compliance with the License.  You can obtain a copy
 * in the file LICENSE in the source distribution or at
 * https://www.openssl.org/source/license.html
 */

#define APPLINK_STDIN   1
#define APPLINK_STDOUT  2
#define APPLINK_STDERR  3
#define APPLINK_FPRINTF 4
#define APPLINK_FGETS   5
#define APPLINK_FREAD   6
#define APPLINK_FWRITE  7
#define APPLINK_FSETMOD 8
#define APPLINK_FEOF    9
#define APPLINK_FCLOSE  10      /* should not be used */

#define APPLINK_FOPEN   11      /* solely for completeness */
#define APPLINK_FSEEK   12
#define APPLINK_FTELL   13
#define APPLINK_FFLUSH  14
#define APPLINK_FERROR  15
#define APPLINK_CLEARERR 16
#define APPLINK_FILENO  17      /* to be used with below */

#define APPLINK_OPEN    18      /* formally can't be used, as flags can vary */
#define APPLINK_READ    19
#define APPLINK_WRITE   20
#define APPLINK_LSEEK   21
#define APPLINK_CLOSE   22
#define APPLINK_MAX     22      /* always same as last macro */

#ifndef APPMACROS_ONLY
# include <stdio.h>
# include <io.h>
# include <fcntl.h>

static void *app_stdin(void)
{
    return stdin;
}

static void *app_stdout(void)
{
    return stdout;
}

static void *app_stderr(void)
{
    return stderr;
}

static int app_feof(FILE *fp)
{
    return feof(fp);
}

static int app_ferror(FILE *fp)
{
    return ferror(fp);
}

static void app_clearerr(FILE *fp)
{
    clearerr(fp);
}

static int app_fileno(FILE *fp)
{
    return _fileno(fp);
}

static int app_fsetmod(FILE *fp, char mod)
{
    return _setmode(_fileno(fp), mod == 'b' ? _O_BINARY : _O_TEXT);
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

__declspec(dllexport)
void **
# if defined(__BORLANDC__)
/*
 * __stdcall appears to be the only way to get the name
 * decoration right with Borland C. Otherwise it works
 * purely incidentally, as we pass no parameters.
 */
__stdcall
# else
__cdecl
# endif
OPENSSL_Applink(void)
{
    static int once = 1;
    static void *OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_MAX + 1] =
        { (void *)APPLINK_MAX };

    if (once) {
        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_STDIN] = app_stdin;
        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_STDOUT] = app_stdout;
        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_STDERR] = app_stderr;
        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_FPRINTF] = fprintf;
        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_FGETS] = fgets;
        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_FREAD] = fread;
        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_FWRITE] = fwrite;
        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_FSETMOD] = app_fsetmod;
        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_FEOF] = app_feof;
        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_FCLOSE] = fclose;

        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_FOPEN] = fopen;
        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_FSEEK] = fseek;
        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_FTELL] = ftell;
        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_FFLUSH] = fflush;
        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_FERROR] = app_ferror;
        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_CLEARERR] = app_clearerr;
        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_FILENO] = app_fileno;

        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_OPEN] = _open;
        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_READ] = _read;
        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_WRITE] = _write;
        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_LSEEK] = _lseek;
        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_CLOSE] = _close;

        once = 0;
    }

    return OPENSSL_ApplinkTable;
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

That's it, this will eliminate the strange behavior of program exit.